# Prove that $\nabla_{-v}f(a) = -\nabla_{v}f(a)$, provided $\nabla_{v}f(a)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Definition: $\nabla_{v}f(a)$ is said to be the directional derivative of $f$ at $a$ along the vector $v$ if $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $\forall h \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$0<|h|<\delta \implies \left|\left| \frac{f(a+hv)-f(a)}{h} - \nabla_{v}f(a) \right|\right|<\epsilon$$

or equivalently,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+hv) - f(a)}{h} = \nabla_{v}f(a).$$

Note that we cannot use the eqaution relating the directional derivative to a the gradient since $f$ may not be differentiable at $a$.

Here is my attempt using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition.

Suppose $\nabla_{v}f(a)$ exists. We want to show that $\nabla_{-v}f(a) = -\nabla_{v}f(a)$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta_{0} >0$ s.t. for any $h \in \mathbb{R}, 0<|h|<\delta_{0}$,

$$\left|\left| \frac{f(a+hv)-f(a)}{h} - \nabla_{v}f(a) \right|\right|<\epsilon.$$

Now pick $\delta = $ (tbd). then for $0<|h|<\delta$,

$$\left|\left| \frac{f(a-hv)-f(a)}{h} + \nabla_{v}f(a) \right|\right|$$

Unfortunately, I got stuck here as i have no idea how to obtain an expression similar to $\left|\left| \frac{f(a+hv)-f(a)}{h} - \nabla_{v}f(a) \right|\right|<\epsilon$ from $\left|\left| \frac{f(a-hv)-f(a)}{h} + \nabla_{v}f(a) \right|\right|$. Any hints/ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Side note: `\Vert` renders slightly better than `||`  for a norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same delta. Note that
$$
 \frac{f(a+h(-v))-f(a)}{h} - (- \nabla_{v}f(a)) = -\left(\frac{f(a+(-h)v)-f(a)}{-h} - \nabla_{v}f(a) \right) \, .
$$
If $0<|h|<\delta_{0}$ then also $0<|-h|<\delta_{0}$
and therefore
$$
\left\Vert \frac{f(a+h(-v))-f(a)}{h} - (- \nabla_{v}f(a))\right\Vert = 
\left\Vert \frac{f(a+(-h)v)-f(a)}{-h} - \nabla_{v}f(a) \right\Vert < \epsilon \, .
$$